# Select a component and display - Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I need to output the text that is selected in the `selectOneMenu`-list. My code is as follows;

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{DataForm.stationed}" id="globalFilter" onchange="carsTable.filter()" style="width:350px;font-size:13px;"  >
    <f:selectItems value="#{DataForm.listHotel}" var="user" itemValue="#{user[1]}" itemDisabled="false" itemLabel="#{user[1]}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{carsTable[1]}" style="width:350px"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

How do I code this?

**EDIT**

**This Listbox is within a `<datatable>`**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form1" >
        <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{DataForm.listHotels}" widgetVar="carsTable" paginator="true" rows="10" onRowSelectComplete="carDialog.show()" emptyMessage="No hospital found with given criteria" selectionMode="single" onRowSelectUpdate="growl" style="width:1400px;font-size:13px;">

            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{DataForm.stationed}" id="globalFilter" onchange="carsTable.filter()" style="width:350px;font-size:13px;"  >
                <f:selectItems value="#{DataForm.listHotel}" var="user" itemValue="#{user[1]}" itemDisabled="false" itemLabel="#{user[1]}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{carsTable[1]}" style="width:350px"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>

        </p:dataTable>

        <f:ajax render= "@form1" >
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{DataForm.stationed}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{DataForm.listHotels}" var="item" itemValue="#{DataForm.listHotels}" itemLabel="#{DataForm.listHotels}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </f:ajax>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove the nested `<h:outputText/>` first, it doesn't really make sense at that position. Also, from your question and example code, it doesn't really become clear what PrimeFaces has to do with it.

To output the selected value, simply print the expression `#{DataForm.stationed}`, since this is the binding that will receive the selected value.

The following example demonstrates this via AJAX, but it would work the same way if you used an action and a regular form submit.

**Facelet**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head />

    <h:body>

        <h:form id="form">

            <f:ajax render="form">
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectOneMenuBean.value}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{selectOneMenuBean.items}" var="item" itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </f:ajax>

            Selected value: #{selectOneMenuBean.value}

        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Bean**

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class SelectOneMenuBean {

    private List<String> items = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    private String value;

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

*p.s.
In your code example the EL names for your beans start with a capital. This is a little against the typical conventions. Also, you might want to pay some attention to your names and types. The bean returns something called `listHotel`, but this is assigned to a variable named `user`, which is then indexed by an integer. I would recommend aligning names (e.g. collection name = `users`, variable name `user`) and using properties instead of indexes (e.g. `user.name`).*

Comment: Hello, I get this exception, any clues ? `SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/test.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'form' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt15`

Comment: You'll need to give your form the id `form` in order to reference it by ID. In the example it's a simple ID, which means it has to be reachable from the ajax tag. Try the example as given, and carefully modify it for your situation until it breaks. Alternatively, you can use `render="@form"` on the ajax tag. This will locate -the- form in which your component is nested, without worrying about names.

Comment: I have edited my question a little bit adding more information to the problem. I still get the same exception even after i add `render="@form"`

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you're doing now. There isn't any `<f:ajax>` tag in your edited question's example code so I can't help there. All I can say now is that the example I gave works. Try it, convince yourself that it works, and then slowly work from the working example code to your own code.

Comment: Well, i added it now. When the `SelectOneMenu` Listbox changes its values, i need its name printed in another `h:outputText `.

Comment: Indeed, that's what the example does ;)

Comment: p.s. `@form1` in your code doesn't make sense. It doesn't refer to an ID. It's `@form` (meaning 'the parent form') or `form1` (meaning 'the component with ID 'form1')